# Windows applications icons, including 24×24 taskbar ones, in 2023

Tags: winapi, icons, taskbar

It's been a decade now (and two major Windows versions) since Microsoft shrunk the "big" taskbar icons (introduced in Windows 7) from 32×32 to 24×24, without providing an option for unpackaged applications to properly set a 24×24 icon to a window (`WM_SETICON` still accepts only two values for `wParam`, etc.).

This is further complicated by the fact that according to `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON)`, the *official* size of a "big" icon is still 32×32.

Has the situation improved in any way since then? Is there any API through which a classic Windows API application can have all its icons work correctly in a native resolution?

- The EXE icon supporting all resolutions the Windows Explorer can show a file at
- The small 16×16 icon in the window titlebar
- The 24×24 icon in the taskbar
- I was about to mention the alt-tab window, but apparently in 10 and above it too switched from 32×32 icons to 24×24 ones

Comment: The idea that icons are 16px in the titlebar and 24px in the taskbar is for the birds. High dpi is here now. You need to supply a wide range of icon sizes. It's enough to use `LoadIcon` and then pass that icon handle to `WM_SETICON` and so long as the resource is an icon group with a good range of sizes, the system will use the right icon for the setting.

Comment: I usually provide 256x256 ("Jumbo" size), 48x48, 32x32 and 16x16 all in RGBA (Vista+), for example https://github.com/smourier/DeviceExplorer/blob/main/DeviceExplorer/DeviceExplorer.ico and have no issue or maybe I don't understand what you mean or what problem you get

Comment: @SimonMourier The problem I get is that the version of the icon that appears in the titlebar is the 32×32 icon, shrunk to 24×24 with all the ugliness that entails. It's like to get a non-resized icon in there.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Last I checked <s>there was no way to trace an individual HICON back to the icon group it was made from,</s> and Windows didn't try either.

Comment: @SimonMourier Oops replace "It's like" with "I'd like".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have confirmed, with a test, that Windows does not bother looking through the icon group. I gave it the COMPLETE range of sizes from 16×16 to 32×32, loaded from the EXE so GetIconInfoEx() would work, and got the 32×32 one shrunk still.

Comment: That's not in line with my experience. I wonder what you and I are doing differently. Did you do WM_SETICON for both icon sizes, small and large? Passing the same icon handle that you got from LoadIcon?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I used WM_SETICON for both icon sizes, but loaded the big one with LoadIcon() and the small one (which is correctly displayed) with LoadImage() instead. I will try passing the same icon handle, perhaps my code was "too right". **EDIT:** After trying that, now I have a shrunk 32*32 icon in both places. I don't know what else I should have expected.

Comment: I wonder if the issue is the resource itself

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Like, you think the order of icon image types within the resource still matters? Unfortunately Visual Studio (even 2022) provides no easy way to reorder them...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I used Gimp to reorder the images. I tried pure ascending order of size, as well as descending order, neither helped.

Comment: I put them together with icofx and then declare them with ICON in my .rc file

Comment: `LoadImageW` accepts any valid .ico file. I can display ico. files of different sizes.https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSQH3.png

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT That's not the question. The question is how to make the taskbar correctly display the 24×24 version of the icon. Or are you suggesting I ask `LoadImage`  for the 24×24 version, set this into `ICON_BIG` and hope no unintended side effects come up?

Comment: @Medinoc Yes. `LoadIcon` has been superseded by the LoadImage function (with `LR_DEFAULTSIZE` and `LR_SHARED` flags set). `Cx` in function `LoadImage`, If this parameter is zero and `LR_DEFAULTSIZE` is not used, the function uses the actual resource height\width.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT Thank you very much, setting the 24×24 version into `ICON_BIG` seems to work correctly indeed (at least at first glance). Now for future-proofing: Since `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON)` still returns 32, **which API** returns the actual taskbar icon size?

Comment: @Medinoc Even if it's not the initial question I try to reply. Try using `getIconInfo` like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmyQj.png

Comment: @Medinoc Have you tried using `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON)`? It returns 16？

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT Yes, `SM_CYSMICON` returns 16 and `SM_CYICON` returns 32.

Comment: @Medinoc So, that's Microsoft defining the size of the system small\large icon. It is by design. Indeed it's not good and unreasonable. I will convert the initial comment to answer.

Comment: I filed this as a bug in the Microsoft Feedback Hub: https://aka.ms/AAmbo9t
Feel free to upvote and/or add comments to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask `LoadImage` for the 24×24 version, set this into `ICON_BIG`.

`LoadIcon` has been superseded by the `LoadImage` function (with `LR_DEFAULTSIZE` and `LR_SHARED` flags set). `Cx\Cy` in function `LoadImage`, If this parameter is zero and `LR_DEFAULTSIZE` is not used, the function uses the actual resource height\width.

Comment: Thanks. And I converted my follow-up question into a separate one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76928082/1455631

Comment: @Medinoc After two days I will test if the code works and my time zone will be two days off. I hope there will be other respondents to solve your question as soon as possible.

Comment: @Medinoc Is this what your want? https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J8X2.png  `GetIconInfo` seems return correct value.

Comment: In this code you passed 24 to `LoadImage()`, right? It is natural to me that GetIconInfo() on an icon loaded by LoadImage() will return the size that was passed to LoadImage(). What I'm looking for in my (now-moved) followup question, is the API that will tell me I should pass 24 to LoadImage() in the first place (or what value to use instead of 24 when DPI is not set to 100%).

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT Do you mind adding sample code. I'm not yet completely sure about all parameters.

By the way this does not fix the issue when the application is pinned to the taskbar but not running.

Comment: @MichaelDietrich Under `WNDCLASSEX wc`, `wc.hIcon= (HICON)LoadImageW(wc.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SPARKLETANK), IMAGE_ICON, 24, 24, NULL);`