# Which windows API returns the taskbar icon size?

Tags: winapi, icons, taskbar, windows-11

Windows 8 and above changed the (default-DPI) size of "big" taskbar icons (introduced in Windows 7) from 32×32 to 24×24. However, `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON)` and `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON)` still return 32 and 16 respectively.

Is there any Windows API that returns the actual size of (by default) 24?

Comment: What about dpi?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well if there's no function that returns the actual size, I guess I'll have to fall back on a function that retrieves the DPI, and then multiply 24 by it (at least until Microsoft decides to change the size again) and figure out what rounding is used. **Edit:** Or are you suggesting the DPI API may contain a function that returns the right size?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is such an API.  You may use [`GetMonitorInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmonitorinfow), and check the values of `MONITORINFO.rcWork` and `MONITORINFO.rcMonitor` ([`MONITORINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-monitorinfo))

Comment: This is for getting the height of the taskbar itself?

Comment: Yes - subtract the size of the working area from that of the monitor.  The result is the taskbar.

Comment: The task bar can be more than one row tall/more than one column wide.

Answer (score -2):

Refer to the Doc:[Class Icons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes#class-icons)

> To assign a large and small icon to a window class, specify the
> handles of the icons in the hIcon and hIconSm members of the
> WNDCLASSEX structure. The icon dimensions must conform to required
> dimensions for large and small class icons. For a large class icon,
> you can determine the required dimensions by specifying the SM_CXICON
> and SM_CYICON values in a call to the GetSystemMetrics function.

Call `GetSystemMetrics` with `SM_CXICON` to retrieve the size of the system large icon. As far as I'm concerned, you should try to set the `hIcon` member of `WNDCLASSA`.

Comment: I explicitly said in the question that `GetSystemMetrics` does not return the size I'm looking for, because since Windows 8, **the taskbar icon size is no longer the system large icon size**.
We have found in the linked thread that setting `hIcon` to an icon of the new 24×24 size works, but I'm trying to get an "official" value for it rather than hard-code it to `24`, because changing DPI settings changes the taskbar icon size.

Comment: “Call GetSystemMetrics with SM_CXICON to retrieve the size of the system large icon.” What I'm explaining is that you couldn't get the size of the taskbar icon with `GetSystemMetrics, because `GetSystemMetrics` gets the size of the system icon.

When Windows displays your app's icon, it will look for an exact size match first. If there is no exact match it will look for the next size above and scale down. There is no api to get the the taskbar icon size.

Comment: If I give Windows (8 or above) a 32×32 icon for my window, Windows will shrink it, transforming a hand-crafted pixel-art icon into a jumbled mess of linerarly-interpolated pixels. I found in the linked thread that if I pass it a 24×24 icon *and the DPI haven't been changed*, the 24×24 icon is correctly displayed. But **nothing** returns this size? Not only did Microsoft break what didn't need fixing, **in over a decade Microsoft still hasn't provided *any* way to fix it?**

Comment: I'd suggest you could submit a feedback request about the issue in the Feedback Hub.